# Retrieve php variable via html name form

Tags: php, html, variables

I need to retrieve an php variable only by knowing it's html input name.

Such as: I know the input's name is admin[username] so I want to get the variable $_POST['admin']['username]

I need this for some sort of validations of the inputs. In other word, I save the html input name when I display the form, but only test it at the next server request, so I don't always know what will be the php variable name, since it can be modified by javascript or I can have array such if the html input name is admin[]

Thank you

Comment: You are looking for `$_POST['admin'][]` array elements?

Comment: your html is as follows? `<input type=text name="admin[username]" />` ?

Comment: @DainisAbols If I pass the string "admin[]" I will be looking for $_POST['admin'][] yes, but it can be simple "admin", "admin[username]", "admin[username][]" or "admin[username][][test]" of course, this is only examples and the names don't really means anything

Comment: @JonTaylor yes something like that, but the name can change, so the complexity of what I'm trying to do :s

Comment: I guess you start with array check and then variable checking inside the array. Can you show what have you built so far?

Comment: @DainisAbols I'm kind of block at the start. I imagine I'll need to split my string containing the variable name, than do some sort of reccursive against $_POST. This will work if the string if "admin" or "admin[test]" but when I get to array "[]" I don't know how to do it...

Comment: This is rather confusing, could you stop telling us what you think you should do about a problem we still don't understand. But clearly explain what you want to do and what code you currently have.

Comment: @timmied I told you what I though I should do because someone ask me to...  

And what part don't you understand? Maybe if you ask for clarification insted of doing that, I may explain more on some details...

Comment: No @DainisAbols asked you to show you what you have built so far, exactly the same thing I am asking. And some underlying clarification wouldn't hurt no. What I currently understand is you post a form values with dynamic keynames within an array. This could be a associative array(admin[username][test]) but you seem to have some difficulty when this array does not have a key (admin[username][]). Something like that.

Comment: @timmied Sorry for trying to give some hint, my bad

So in the simpliest term possible: an function that will recieve an parameter, this parameter is a string, if the string is "admin" the function will return the value of $_POST['admin'] if the string is "admin[test]" -> $_POST['admin']['test'], if the string is "admin[]" the function will return an array of all the value of $_POST['admin'] and if the string is "admin[][test]" the function will return an array containing all the key test inside the array $_POST['admin']

Comment: I posted something I think it might be the answer to your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$postdata = get_associative_array_from_post_data($post['admin']);

function get_associative_array_from_post_data($array){
    if(isAssoc($array)){
        /*foreach($array as $key=>$value){
            $your_key = $key;
            $your_value = $value;
        }*/
        return $array;
    }
    else{ //if the post array has no keys, search for arrays within this 
        $key_collection=array();
        foreach($array as $sub_array){

            foreach($sub_array as $key=>$value){
                $key_collection[$key][] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $key_collection;
    }

}    



function isAssoc($arr)
{
    return array_keys($arr) !== range(0, count($arr) - 1);
}
```

If you post:

admin[username] = 'test' and admin[email] = 'test@example.com'

you will get

```
$postdata = array('username'=>'test', 'email'=>'test@example.com');
```

If you post :
admin[][username] = 'test' and admin[][username] = 'test2'
admin[][email] = 'test@example.com' and admin[][email] = 'test2@example.com'

You will get:

```
$postdata = array(
                      'username'=>array('test', 'test2'),
                      'email'=>array('test@example.com', 'test2@example.com')
                 );
```

Comment: I like your idea to validate if this is an associate array, this will certainly help me  

Thx